# Blender and Gimp linear workflow

Tags: color

a question for users who use Blender together with Gimp for Post-processing, Texturing, etc. etc.

How to work in Gimp 2.10.8 as if you were working in Nuke or Blender Compositor? I'll explain.

When I go into Nuke or Blender I have the possibility to linearize the input data (if these are sRGB), how can I do this in Gimp? Also in both Blender and Nuke I can turn on and off the sRGB LUT that is applied in display, is there something like that in Gimp?

Furthermore, Gimp now works at 32bit float, but are the calculations done linearly or are there limitations?

In output phase how can I then return to sRGB by applying the LUT in the data?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: This sounds more like question about GIMP than Blender

Comment: You should just save renders as exr's, keep them linear through the entire workflow

Comment: GIMP is mangled up. Don’t expect it to do anything properly, and given it is display referred, it’s impossible to do scene referred work with efficiently.